# Read the Table Name and Column Names from .ctl file in Java

Tags: java, string, ctl

Hello I am trying to read the read the table name and column names for a sql query for my test validation

I have a .ctl file which has the table details as shown

```html
LOAD DATA APPEND
  INTO TABLE ALM_LAV_CD_BSTG
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '~~' 
TRAILING NULLCOLS                                                               
(                                                                               
   ALM_VERS_ID                      DECIMAL EXTERNAL NULLIF (ALM_VERS_ID=BLANKS)
 , LAV_CD                           CHAR NULLIF (LAV_CD=BLANKS)                 
 , LAV_CD_OFSE                      INTEGER EXTERNAL NULLIF (LAV_CD_OFSE=BLANKS)
 , LAV_CD_AMT                       DECIMAL EXTERNAL NULLIF (LAV_CD_AMT=BLANKS) 
 , EXPRT_DT                         DATE "YYYY-MM-DD"
 , DUA_INSRT_ID                     CHAR NULLIF (DUA_INSRT_ID=BLANKS)           
 , DUA_INSRT_TMSTP                  TIMESTAMP "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF6"                                            
 , DUA_UPDT_ID                      CHAR NULLIF (DUA_UPDT_ID=BLANKS)            
 , DUA_UPDT_TMSTP                   TIMESTAMP "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF6"                                            
 , DUA_VERS_NBR                     DECIMAL EXTERNAL NULLIF (DUA_VERS_NBR=BLANKS)                                                                               
)
```

My requirement is to read table name into string and column names ignoring EXPRT_DT into string

My code is as below

```js
package com.cf.ODSAutomation;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

public class ReadControlFile {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  // Control Files Folder Path

  File path = new File("C:\\ODS\\control_File");
  final FileNameExtensionFilter extensionFilter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Control Files", "ctl");
  File[] files = path.listFiles();
  System.out.println("Number of Control Files : " + files.length);

  // Looping the files in the folder

  for (final File file : path.listFiles()) {
   if (extensionFilter.accept(file)) {
    System.out.println("File Name : " + file.getName().trim());
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    String currentLine = reader.readLine();
    while (currentLine != null) {
     builder.append(currentLine);
     builder.append("\n");
     currentLine = reader.readLine();
    }

    // Appending all lines into single line
    System.out.println(builder.toString());

    // Getting Table Name
    String temp[] = builder.toString().split("TABLE ");
    String temp1[] = temp[1].split("_BSTG");
    String TableName = temp1[0].trim();
    System.out.println("Table Name : " + TableName);

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]+_*");

    Matcher m1 = p.matcher(temp[1]);

    System.out.println("Words from string \"" + temp[1] + "\" : ");
    while (m1.find()) {
     System.out.println(m1.group());
    }

    reader.close();

   }
  }

 }

}
```

I am able to read the table name using Strings class but I am not able to get the column name.

My Desire result is to get the column names  appended in a string with comma separated like below

ALM_VERS_ID , LAV_CD , LAV_CD_OFSE  , LAV_CD_AMT, EXPRT_DT , DUA_INSRT_ID , DUA_INSRT_TMSTP, DUA_UPDT_ID , DUA_UPDT_TMSTP, DUA_VERS_NBR

Currently my Result is

ALM_
LAV_
CD_
BSTG
FIELDS
TERMINATED
BY
TRAILING
NULLCOLS
ALM_
VERS_
ID
DECIMAL
EXTERNAL
NULLIF
ALM_
VERS_
ID
BLANKS
LAV_
CD
CHAR
NULLIF
LAV_
CD
BLANKS
LAV_
CD_
OFSE
INTEGER
EXTERNAL
NULLIF
LAV_
CD_
OFSE
BLANKS
LAV_
CD_
AMT
DECIMAL
EXTERNAL
NULLIF
LAV_
CD_
AMT
BLANKS
EXPRT_
DT
DATE
YYYY
MM
DD
DUA_
INSRT_
ID
CHAR
NULLIF
DUA_
INSRT_
ID
BLANKS
DUA_
INSRT_
TMSTP
TIMESTAMP
YYYY
MM
DD
HH
MI
SS
FF
DUA_
UPDT_
ID
CHAR
NULLIF
DUA_
UPDT_
ID
BLANKS
DUA_
UPDT_
TMSTP
TIMESTAMP
YYYY
MM
DD
HH
MI
SS
FF
DUA_
VERS_
NBR
DECIMAL
EXTERNAL
NULLIF
DUA_
VERS_
NBR
BLANKS

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/5221149)

Comment: There is lot of effort put to get the desired result in multiple ways, I am getting other String as well with my required column names . Removed Help from the question

Comment: What desired result? You don't show what you expected to get, or what you're actually getting. You don't show where your debugging has suggested the problem might be. You haven't even formatted the code correctly, as it is not JavaScript snippets.

Comment: Can't see your desired result in that comment, but since you should be clarifying the question in a comment anyway, it doesn't matter. **Edit** the question to clarify it. Delete the comment. And remember to also show us what you actually do get from your code.

Comment: Done in the question as well

Comment: @Andreas - IS it all ok to answer my question

Comment: Will your answer be of use to anyone else, or is it too specific to just your problem? If *generally* useful, then yes, you can answer your own question. If not useful in general, just delete the question.

Comment: I did not get the answer yet. I am asking is the question format ok ? Can some one answer my query

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were asking if you could answer your own question. --- No, the question format is not ok. Do *you* think it looks ok/readable, with your "desire" and your "result" just showing one big block of unformatted text? --- And your code still shows as JavaScript snippets, but the code is not JavaScript, is it?

Comment: The first block of code is the .ctl file

the second block of code is java

The output what ever i am getting is the console output . Iam getting the same way in console here. Just copy pasted the same

Comment: Really? According to the raw source of the question, each word is on its own line, but the question we can see here has all the words together in one long (word-wrapped) line, so *"Iam getting the same way in console here"* doesn't seem to be correct. What we're seeing is *not* what you're seeing in your console. Fix the formatting of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look into the C# solution that I have coded for you to process the control files. I happened to name the control file with *.txt.

Coded a Control File Parser for processing the table name, all column names per control file.

https://github.com/ranjancse26/ControlFileProcessor

You can easily reverse engineer code from C# to Java.